# Update state from external source for single item in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm using a `ListView.builder` to manage a long list of widgets that each have a progress bar.

I've reviewed other answers and made sure that each `Widget` constructed by the `ListView.builder` has its own state. In my case `ConversionGroupWidget` manages its own state.

The problem is that the updates come in from a `Stream`. When listening for stream updates, I create a new widget if needed and then `setState()` which refreshes the entire list. However if the update is only a progress change, how can I select from the `ListView` the single item that needs a `setState()` call? Below, the line with the `TODO` comment.

```
class ProgressView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<ProgressStatus> statusStream;

  const ProgressView({super.key, required this.statusStream});

  @override
  State<ProgressView> createState() => _ProgressViewState();
}

class _ProgressViewState extends State<ProgressView> {
  final ProgressData conversionProgress = ProgressData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.statusStream.listen((update) async {
      final group = conversionProgress.groupToUpdate(update);

      if (group == null) {
        await conversionProgress.addConversionGroup(update);
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        // TODO!
      }
    });
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: conversionProgress.conversionGroups.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
          var group = conversionProgress.conversionGroups[idx];

          return Container(
              padding: Style.prefsPaneSideInsets,
              child: Column(children: [
                Style.prefsPaneSectionVSpacer,
                ConversionGroupWidget(
                  groupStatus: group,
                )
              ]));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe `StatefulBuilder` will help in this case

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that having the individual `Widget` be stateless is fundamentally incompatible with the `Stream`.

The `Stream` events update the `Widget`s so by definition if the `Widget` is stateless it cannot be updated. That leads to having a big global state and calling `setState()` to update everything at once.

I solved this by using stateful widgets and having each `Widget` take a filtered `Stream` in its constructor. Then in `initState` the state calls `listen()` on the `widget.stream` and updates itself that way.